# microsoft SQL azure studio division by zero when dividing numbers less than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, divide-by-zero

I have created this demo table -

```
create table main(
    val1 int,
    val2 int
);
```

inserted a couple of values

```
 insert into main values(0.54,0.56);
```

when I run this query

```
select val1/val2 from main
```

I get a 'Divide by zero error encountered.' This is happening because the denominator is rounded off to zero before the division happens. How do I solve this problem? 
When I try casting the values to numeric the error still persists.

```
select cast(val1 as numeric(3,2)) / cast(val2 as numeric(3,2)) 
from main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check what the values in your table actually are... After your `INSERT` if you perform:

```
SELECT val1, val2
FROM dbo.main;
```

You'll notice that the values are `0` and `0` respectively. Therefore you get the error. `0.56` is not an `int`, it's a `decimal`, so when you `INSERT` it into an `int`, it becomes an `int`.

Change the data type of your columns. Perhaps:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.main(val1 decimal(3,2),
                      val2 decimal(3,2));
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df6f1dbd0c09ef7d561b3d32616c2dda)